# Creating separate log files for virtual hosts based on ServerName directive in Apache

Tags: apache2

I want to know is their way to get log file name from ServerName instead of manually setting the log name

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mike-dev.website


 UseCanonicalName On
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

      
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/%{ServerName}-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/%{ServerName}-access.log combined


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =tariq-sajid-dev.website
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

the file is creating with this name

```
%{ServerName}-access.log
%{ServerName}-error.log
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mike-dev.website


 UseCanonicalName On
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

      
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/%{ServerName}-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/%{ServerName}-access.log combined


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} = mike-dev.website
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I am expecting the each log filename should be like this

```
mike-dev.website-access.log
mike-dev.website-error.log
```